# Pandas getting values splitted in variables

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv

So, I'm trying to use pandas **to go through a CSV line** by line and split the value of every column into variables.

```
csv = pandas.read_csv('file.csv', sep = ';', usecols = ['ref', 'design', 'quant'])
```

I need to get the **ref**, **design** and **quant** values into **3 separated variables** so I can process it, after that go to the next line.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Could you add your expected result to the question as well (you can use the [edit] button)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this will do what you want.

I suppose `file.csv` is something as follows:

```
ref;design;quant;xxx
1;2;3;4
5;6;7;8
```

To separate 3 cols to 3 variables, you can use `A, B, C = [csv[i] for i in csv]`

```
>>> csv = pandas.read_csv('file.csv', sep = ';', usecols = ['ref', 'design', 'quant'])
>>> A, B, C = [csv[i] for i in csv]
>>> A
0    1
1    5
Name: ref, dtype: int64
>>> B
0    2
1    6
Name: design, dtype: int64
>>> C
0    3
1    7
Name: quant, dtype: int64
```

You can of course also use `A, B, C = [csv[i].tolist() for i in csv]` to transform them to a list.

---

If you want to process line by line, use `itertuples()`:

```
for idx, ref, design, quant in csv.itertuples():
    print(ref, design, quant)
```

Comment: That's excatly what i was trying to archive, thank you so much!